# Синхронизация потоков с помощью Event c++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, события, синхронизация

Необходимо, чтобы нить t4 ждала события просчета времени "time = 1000 * (getTime() - time);" и после этого запускалась. Как реализовать? Нужен именно Event (такое задание)

```
// Get start time
long time = getTime();

// Thread procession
thread t1(process, filenames, 0);
thread t2(process, filenames, 1);
thread t3(process, filenames, 2);
thread t4(foutput, "Time total", "", time);

// Join
t1.join();
t2.join();
t3.join();

// Get total time
// Здесь должен быть Event
time = 1000 * (getTime() - time);

// Здесь должна сработать нить t4 
t4.join();
```

Comment: Лучше делать задержку в самом потоке, а не в запускающем, да еще и после `join()` - которые непонятно когда завершатся. Ну и понять ваше `time = 1000 * (getTime() - time);` - лично меня не хватает. Поясните понятнее, что вы хотите?...

Comment: t1,t2,t3 - Обрабатывают массивы чисел в файлах.     time = 1000 * (getTime() - time); - считает время затраченное на все потоки. t4 - пишет время в файл. Стоит задача - синхронизировать потоки с помощью Event. Ума не приложу куда его пихать этот Event, по этому решил, что поток t4 должен ждать события "потоки 1-3 закончились, время посчиталось" потом стартует поток 4.